# how to sort object array by key in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, ksort

I have an object array

```
 <pre>stdClass Object
(
    [October] => 13.88888888888889
    [January] => 11.11111111111111
    [April] => 17.77777777777778
    [February] => 12.777777777777777
    [August] => 17.77777777777778
    [June] => 16.11111111111111
    [May] => 16.11111111111111
    [July] => 17.77777777777778
    [November] => 12.222222222222221
    [March] => 12.777777777777777
    [December] => 11.11111111111111
    [September] => 15.0
)
</pre>
```

I want to sort this array on the basis of month (key)

I used ksort() function but error coming that it must be array not object.

Then I converted it to array as array($data); and then used ksort() again but still no result.

Please help my guys how to do??

Comment: @MihaiIorga thats is array while i have stdclassobject

Comment: So turn it into array ... use $std = `json_encode($std)`, `$std = json_decode($std, true)`

Comment: @MihaiIorga please check again my question

Comment: Did you read my last comment ?

Comment: not clealry can you give me answer with solution.

Comment: You have to work that out, here is how you turn stdClass Object: http://codepad.org/eLdn29Dm

Comment: Try This `ksort($month);// Array object
foreach ($month as $key => $val) {
 echo "$key = $val\n";
}`

Answer (score 0):

you should try the following code for your task:

$months=array("October" => "6.2","January" => "0.2","April" => "1.5","February" => "0.2","August" => "5.4","June" => "3.1","May" => "4.5","July" => "4.2","November" => "2.5",   "March" => "0.5","December" => "0.7","September" => "6.9");

```
        ksort($months);

                   foreach($months as $key=>$keyvalue)//$x=>$x_value
        {
        echo "<br>".$key."=>".$keyvalue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ksort() but you will first need to turn your object into an array.

You can do this with json_encode/json_decode

```
$array = json_decode( json_encode( $stdObject ), true );

ksort( $array );

foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    echo $key. '=' .$val.'<br />'
}
```